# Dynamic library linking issue

Tags: xcode, cocoa, macos, dylib, libusb-1.0

I am trying to link a dynamic library in my COCOA application but I am getting the following strange error:

**dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libusb-0.1.4.dylib**

I want to link this library from application (Mac OS) directory as I don't want user to have install anything. Although I have properly linked the library in frameworks and added it to target copy build phase but it's still complaining that the library is missing. Other two libraries which I linked are working fine but libusb-0.1.4.dylib is causing problem. Could anybody please tell me how to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to fix this issue by modifying paths in dynamic libraries using **otool** and **install_name_tool** utilities. For reference please consult: [Dynamic Libraries, RPATH, and Mac OS](http://blogs.oracle.com/dipol/entry/dynamic_libraries_rpath_and_mac)

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic library can't be moved. Its path is determined at compilation time, and cannot change.

This is certainly why you are getting the error.

You should recompile that specific library as a static one.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am able to fix the issue by modifying paths in dynamic libraries.

Comment: But the path can be relative, e.g. loader_path, executable_path, rpath.

Comment: @Bavarious `LC_LOAD_DYLIB` command in `Mach-O` executable header format always uses full paths.